# Computing the derivative: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left\{ \int_0^t \int_{x - t + \eta}^{x + t - \eta} F(\xi,\eta) \,d\xi\, d\eta \right\}$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let's say that $F$ is a nice well-behaved function. How would I compute the following derivative?

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left\{ \int\limits_0^t \int\limits_{x - t + \eta}^{x + t - \eta} F(\xi,\eta) \,d\xi \,d\eta \right\}$$

This is what I have so far:

$$= \int_0^t \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left\{ \int\limits_{x - t + \eta}^{x + t - \eta} F(\xi,\eta) \, d\xi \right\} \, d\eta $$

$$= \int_0^t \left\{ F(x - t + \eta, \eta) + F(x + t - \eta, \eta) \right\} \, d\eta $$

$$= \int_0^t F(x - t + \eta, \eta) \,d\eta + \int_0^t F(x + t - \eta, \eta) \, d\eta $$

Is this correct? Or am I missing a minus sign in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x f(x) \, dx=f(x)$$
and
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_x^a f(x) \, dx=-\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x f(x)=-f(x)$$
and similarly
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^{g(x)} f(x) \, dx=f(x)g'(x)$$

You should have,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left\{ \int\limits_{x - t + \eta}^{x + t - \eta} F(\xi,\eta) d\xi \right\}=
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left\{ \int\limits_{x - t + \eta}^{0} F(\xi,\eta) d\xi + \int\limits_{0}^{x + t - \eta} F(\xi,\eta) d\xi \right\}\\
=-F(x - t + \eta,\eta) + F(x + t - \eta,\eta)= F(x + t - \eta,\eta)-F(x - t + \eta,\eta) $$
and therefore 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left\{ \int\limits_{0}^{t} \int\limits_{x - t + \eta}^{x + t - \eta} F(\xi,\eta) d\xi d\eta \right\}
=\int_0^t F(x + t - \eta,\eta)-F(x - t + \eta,\eta)d\eta$$